# How to execute a shell command in vi with one function key?

Tags: shell, editor, vi

We can execute a shell command in vi. For example, typing in :!ls we can list files at the current directory. We can send the same command by typing in :!! in vi.

I am wondering if I could replace :!! with F7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me

`:nnoremap <F7> :!!<CR>`